# Hosts private IP addresses changed after modifying systems timezone, date and time

Tags: networking, ssh, connection, timeout

Hope everybody feels good. I searched online but I think it might be hard to find an answer. Here's my problem:

Last Friday I wanted to do a test on my remote hosts, I changed the timezone, date and time to the next DST date/time scheduled. After a couple of minutes, when trying to reconnect to the hosts using SSH, I've noticed a "Network error: Connection timed out" on all the hosts.

So I thought it was related to the network lease period but it's set to 24 hours and it occurred before the 24 hours passed. I am fairly new to networking and stuff. Maybe it's a dumb question. If so, please pardon me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you changed the time on those hosts, it is conceivable that they thought their lease had expired and got a new one. However, hosts that you want to access from outside should have fixed IP addresses from the start, otherwise you're inviting trouble...

Comment: ok thats what I though but wasnt 100% sure. im only accessing through internal network but yeah, thanks for the answer and the advice. have a nice day